# Correct usage of ?? operator

Tags: php, php-7

In my project, i have an ajax.php which is handling all AJAX POST requests. It gets the command, verifies all the required arguments exist and pass it off to the relevant class.

I've seen the new '??' operator and have started verifying the POST arguments like this,

```
$name = $_POST['name'] ?? die('{"result":0, "data":"name not provided"}');
$state = $_POST['state'] ?? die('{"result":0, "data":"state not provided"}');
```

Which I think looks better than,

```
$name = isset($_POST['blah']) ? $_POST['blah'] : die('{"result":0, "data":"blah not provided"}');
```

I've deployed and confirmed it is working but Intellij is chucking a hissy fit about unreachable code after the first usage. I'd like to know if i'm either misusing the syntax and could potentially be fixed or if Intellij just isn't on the ball.

I'm always paranoid about bad practices so would like to know your opinions on both the syntax usage as well as the whole ajax.php. Is it bad to have a page dedicated to basically verifying post arguments exist? (it doesn't verify the actual data, just that it *has* data). I've also wondered if i should split ajax.php into a route to try and split it up? Would you ever consider doing something like

```
foreach (['name', 'state'] AS $arg) {
  $$arg = $_POST[$arg] ?? die("{\"result\":0, \"data\":\"$arg not provided\"}");
}
```

which can then either return the processed value or throw an exception/die if missing or would you prefer having each argument per line?

Comment: check your intellij settings (idk about intellik though, but phpstorm - which is based on intellij - allows to set php language version/interpreter). Your operator  usage is totally ok with me.

Comment: It's basically PHPStorm anyways when using PHP through the plugin. Language has been set to PHP7 and i'm running EAP so up-to-date. It doesn't complain about the first usage, just marks all the following lines as unreachable. Makes me think it's misinterpreting the die()

Comment: I'm also considering just doing a list($one, $two) = [$_POST['one'], $_POST['two']]; Since i'm the sole coder of the project, i can make sure i'm always providing the required arguments to bypass checking but just feels...unclean

Comment: I think you have two questions here, and should separate them out. The first is about ?? and is a good question for here; the second is about your coding tactics, and perhaps belongs on Code Review, not here. Either way stick to one question per... erm... question (if you see what I mean).

Comment: Just a tip: don't make assumptions (or excuses!) about you being the only coder on the project. If yer thinking "I can just take this short cut because [...]" then you probably shouldn't ;-) It's an easy route to go down, though, no doubt.

Comment: I would guess that PHPStorm will always assume this is unreachable because it doesn't know what's inside `$_POST` and will therefore just assume it is empty, and therefore that the `??` will take the right branch.

Comment: @Andrea but by that logic it's get it wrong on a simple `if` condition testing the same thing (which it doesn't). It's simply a glitch in their code-time parser, I think. Code inaccessibility checks don't (/can't) consider runtime things such as values of variables for that exact reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a glitch in Intellij. I get the same with PHPStorm 10. You can easily test this to demonstrate your code *works* as you'd expect it to, and that's the proof in the pudding, not how some IDE happens to (miss-)parse it.

If you felt like being helpful, perhaps raise a ticket with JetBrains?

I'll leave the second part of your overall question as - as I indicated in my comment above - it *is* a separate question, and should be presented accordingly. And probably over on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you do shift it there... make sure to cross ref back here :-)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I've asked the latter question over on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/131393/handling-large-amount-s-of-ajax-post-commands  . Not positive what you mean by cross-referencing though

Comment: Just providing a link, like you did.